# Siri will not understand one particular word I say and its driving me nuts

Tags: iphone, siri

In Australia one of our major supermarkets is Coles and I have their app.

Everytime I say the word "Coles" Siri interprets it as "Kohls" so it can not find the app or the shopping list or ANYTHING associated with Coles.

No matter what weird and wonderful pronunciations I have tried she just keeps hearing Kohls.

Even as I say it I can see she sometimes puts Coles in the speech bubble but then it is auto changed to Kohls.

Apart from many other issues minor but irritating with her this one really is annoying.

How can I retrain her?

Comment: I think you need to add the name to contacts and then add a phonetic spelling to the contact. And some people think that once you do that you need to turn dictation off and back on again.

Comment: How does adding an app name to Co tracts work?

Comment: It allows Siri to recognize the word and (probably) give more priority to recognizing it

Answer (score 1):

Man, I understand your problem - even I used to have similar problems. But you can try this trick for short words.

Instead of pronouncing the whole word, just read out the letters. For example, instead of Coles, spell C-O-L-E-S and it works just fine. I know this isn’t the best solution, but it works fine for short words. Also, try changing the Siri language to UK English, it works a lot better according to me.

Answer (score -1):

Tell Siri to "learn how to pronounce **coles**" or if she has mispronounced it already, you can say, "That's not how you say that."

Siri will quickly get over any embarrassment and ask, "OK, how do you pronounce the name **(coles)**?" Say the name correctly, and Siri will listen and offer you a few pronunciation choices. You can play each option and select the one that sounds the best.

**

### First add the **coles contact**

**